# How to phrase the sentences correctly?

Tags: sentence-construction

Say if I go to a hotel and want to ask them what they provide for breakfast,
What is the right way to ask the question?

Can I say:

> What's for breakfast?

And what is the right way to reply to the to the question?

Is it correct to say:

> We offer bread and milk for breakfast?

Comment: You can always ask if it's possible to look at the breakfast menu!

Comment: *What's for breakfast?* strongly implies that the speaker assumes there's ***only one type*** of breakfast available (which arguably invites a lazy cook to only identify the one that's easiest to serve). So I might go for *What **breakfasts** do you have?*, to imply that ***I expect to be offered a choice***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I say: *What's for breakfast?*

Sure you can. We always ask our spouse/parents/friends this question. But I think I agree with FumbleFingers that it *"strongly implies that the speaker assumes there's only one type of breakfast available"* (well, may be not "strongly").

Now this "*one*" type can include eggs, bread, and a glass of milk. So, if you are in a hotel where they serve only one type of breakfast that varies by days (e.g., eggs and bread on Saturday; pumpkin pie, croissants, and fruits on Sunday; and yogurt, pancakes, and juice on Monday) you can surely ask *"What's for breakfast?"* - because you don't know what type it will be (even though you know there will be one).

If you are in a hotel that has a wide range of items, you can ask

(a) What breakfasts do you have? (FumbleFingers) 
(b) Can I get a breakfast menu, please? (Ronald Sole)

> Is it correct to say: *We offer bread and milk for breakfast?*

Sure, if there is just that or a very few items which the guest can remember. If there are many items, you could say

> We actually have a great selection of items. Would you like a menu, [sir/madam]?

or, you can be proactive and say

> We actually have a great selection of items. I will bring you a menu, [sir/madam].

For some reason, I don't prefer the use of "offer". There is nothing wrong with it grammatically or idiomatically. I would say "We *have* coffee" rather than "We *offer* coffee". Its a personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

> What's for breakfast?

This asks the general question of what is being served.

> We offer bread and milk for breakfast.

With a period at the end, you answer the question.

Though, depending on culture, bread by itself could be a bit lacking or non-descriptive for breakfast.

You may say something like:

> We offer pastries and milk for breakfast.

or

> We offer cereals and milk for breakfast.